# Причастие "летящий" от глагола 2-го спряжения

Tags: глаголы, причастия, спряжение

Действительные причастия настоящего времени от глаголов первого спряжения образуются с помощью суффикса ***-ющ-***. От какого глагола в таком случае образовано причастие "летящий"?

Answer (score 2):

Летать - летающий - 1 спр.

Лететь-летящий -2 спр.

Некоторые глаголы на -ЕТЬ, например,ЛЕТЕТЬ, ШУМЕТЬ, СОПЕТЬ, ЗВЕНЕТЬ, ГОРЕТЬ, а также некоторые глаголы на -АТЬ, например, КРИЧАТЬ, МЫЧАТЬ, не первого, а второго спряжения, потому что тип их спряжения мы определяем **не по концовке инфинитива, а по УДАРНЫМ личным окончаниям:** ты летишь, мы летим, они летят; он кричит, вы кричите, они кричат и т. п.

Таким образом, существуют 2 способа определения типа спряжения у глаголов:

1. по личными окончаниям) используется для определения типа спряжения у глаголов с УДАРНЫМИ личными окончаниями (лететь-летит-летишь, летим, летите, **летят-летящий**-2 спр.);
2. по концовке неопределённой формы (инфинитива) определяем тип спряжения у глаголов с БЕЗУДАРНЫМИ личными окончаниями (летать-летаю, летаешь, летает, летаем, летаете, летают). Личные окончания безударные. Летать - на -ать, 1 спр.

При этом если в глаголе есть приставка ВЫ-, то её отбрасываем, так как она перетягивает на себя ударение: Вылетит - летит.

При этом необходимо помнить о том, что глаголы ХОТЕТЬ, БЕЖАТЬ и производные от них – разноспрягаемые, а глаголы ДАТЬ, СОЗДАТЬ, ЕСТЬ и производные от них спрягаются особо.

Answer (score 1):

[Лете́ть](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/chasti-rechi/glagol/kakogo-spryazheniya-glagol-letet.html) — это глагол несовершенного вида, II спряжения.

Из "Русской корпусной грамматики":
Основа действительных причастий настоящего времени образуется путем присоединения к основе настоящего времени глаголов суффиксов *-ущ* (орфографически также *-ющ*) для глаголов первого спряжения и ***-ащ*** (орфографически также ***-ящ***) для глаголов второго спряжения. Действительные причастия настоящего времени образуются только от глаголов несовершенного вида.

Глагол "лететь" заканчивается на *-еть*, но в его ударном личном окончании пишется буква «и», поэтому он принадлежит ко второму спряжению.
Лет/е́ть — ты лет/и́шь — лет/я́щий;
пыхте́ть — пыхти́шь — пыхтя́щий.

Comment: А как же тогда причастие "летающий"?

Comment: Лета́ть (несовершенный вид, I спряжение) — лета́/ешь (лета́/ем, лета́/ют) — лета́/ющий. https://udarenieru.ru/index.php?doc=%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C

Comment: @ВладимирЖеребцов Суффикс _-ющ_ добавляется к основе (лета-). https://russkiiyazyk.ru/sostav-slova/osnova-slova.html#:~:text=%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%E2%80%94%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C,%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5.